# validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Jquery : I have a text box and after that a label 
[image: text box label]

On validation error, the label is going down like **"Please enter a valid number"** minutes 
The html code for the above is

```
    <div>
        <input id='txtBox1' type="text" style='width: 50px' />
        <div style='display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 3px; margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 2px; text-align: left'>
        minutes
       <span style="position: relative; top: 2px; display: inline-block"></span>
   </div>
```

How can we position the error so that it comes below but does interferes with the rest of the label?? 
Thanks..

Comment: You could use the validate plugin for jQuery -- http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Actually i m using the same plugin...i checked in the solution...it does not offer this advantage...

Comment: +1. I had similar problem and ended up with custom validation and display code

Comment: Hey, Sandeep any clues on how to get around this...
One solution that i tried is to put an error container and display all messages in that..But if the form is long enough it takes effort to scroll though and find all such fields.